# Reiniciar contador de visitas php cookies

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente código de php:

```
session_start();
if ( isset( $_COOKIE[ 'visitas' ] ) ) {
    
    setcookie( 'visitas', $_COOKIE[ 'visitas' ] + 1, time() + 3600 * 24 );
    $mensaje = 'Numero de visitas: '.$_COOKIE[ 'visitas' ];
}
else {
    
    setcookie( 'visitas', 1, time() + 3600 * 24 );
    $mensaje = 'Esta es tu primera visita';
}
?>
    <?php echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                  '.$mensaje.'
                </div>';
    ?>
/* Fuera del código php en la parte del html*/
    <a href="eje6.php?resetar"><input type="button" value="Recargar"></a>
    <a href="eje6.php"><input type="button" value="Recargar"></a>
```

¿Como consigo que ese resetear reinicie el contador de la página a 0?
No soy capaz de conseguir que el botón de resetear reinicie el contador a 0. Lo dado a que sigue subiendo incesantemente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así:

Revisar si ha hecho click en el boton `reset`  con variable `$_GET`

```
session_start();

//revisamos si ha hecho click en el boton
if($_GET["resetear"]){
  $_COOKIE["visitas"]=0;
}


if ( isset( $_COOKIE[ 'visitas' ] ) ) {
    
    setcookie( 'visitas', $_COOKIE[ 'visitas' ] + 1, time() + 3600 * 24 );
    $mensaje = 'Numero de visitas: '.$_COOKIE[ 'visitas' ];
}
else {
    
    setcookie( 'visitas', 1, time() + 3600 * 24 );
    $mensaje = 'Esta es tu primera visita';
}

echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">'.$mensaje.'</div>';
 ?>
/* Fuera del código php en la parte del html*/
    <a href="eje6.php?resetar=1"> Resetear</a>
    <a href="eje6.php">Recargar</a>
```